# Can I use jquery and default both JavaScript files in single Rails application?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Please can some one explain me whether I can use both of default and jQuery in single rails application ??? Because I currently working with rails project which developed using default JavaScript file but I need to use jQuery JavaScript file as well so is it possible.

Comment: jquery is javascript you can use it along with simple JS

Comment: Doesn't it create problems when we use both in single page ??

Comment: Which version of rails are you using ? Is it greater than 3 or less than

Comment: no I'm using rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 1):

nope the problem arises when you use multiple plugins on the same page or you use more than one JS liberaries on the same page like `jquery` and `dojo` for that you have to use [**`noConflict`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) but if you want to use javasctipt along with jquery on the same page that is not a problem.

[how to use jquery.noConflict property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1391950/413670)

Answer (score 1):

Default library in 2.3.8 is prototype and that's conflicting when you are using ....

Just add the library in the below format :

```
<head>          
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/obp/js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/obp/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
        var $j = jQuery;
    </script>
</head>
```